# How can I use idempotency in Chef Opscode to execute a mount resource only once?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mount, chef-infra

I can not find how to mount a device in linux only once with chef. Meaning on the other chef client the resource should not execute because a device there has already been mounted to a specific path. 
How can I use chef's idempotency to do this? ...

This is the log stacktrace that I see in the end of chef-client log

```
[2013-11-06T23:12:28+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-11-06T23:12:29+00:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json

[2013-11-06T23:12:29+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete

[2013-11-06T23:12:29+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

[2013-11-06T23:12:29+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: mount[/testpath] (mycookbook::myrecipe line 53) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '32'


STDOUT: 

STDERR: mount: /dev/xvdb already mounted or /testpath busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/xvdb is already mounted on /testpath

---- End output of mount -t auto -o defaults /dev/xvdb /testpath ----

Ran mount -t auto -o defaults /dev/xvdb /testpath returned 32
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [mount](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_mount.html) resource:

```
mount '/testpath' do
  device '/dev/xvdb'
  action [:mount, :enable]
end
```

Comment: that is what I am using. The issue that I am having is that chef is executing the same block again when I run chef-client again. That is not what I want. What I want is chef to run that block that you mentioned only once ... only one time.

Comment: @Becks it won't perform mount action if /dev/xvdb was mounted. it filters the output of command `mount` to check if `/dev/xvdb` is included. see [mount resource provider](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/mount/mount.rb#L76)

Comment: so the problem was that I had not put '/' in front of my testpath ... hence the mount resource was not able to identify if /testpath has already been created or not ... Simple syntax mistake with big potential for failure :D ... thank you @shawnzhu

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was that I had not put '/' in front of my testpath ... hence the mount resource was not able to identify if */testpath* has already been created or not ... Simple syntax mistake with big potential for failure :D ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone lands here mounting nfs (or [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)) volumes on Amazon Linux (ALAMI), the trick is to preface the device path with `//`. You'll notice that `mount` output on ALAMI includes that. Note that if you mount at the root of EFS, just a single `/` is shown and your recipe should match.

Here is a working example:

```
mount /mnt/mydev do
  device "nfsserver://remotepath/subdir"
  fstype 'nfs'
  action [:mount, :enable]
end
```

Here is the output of `mount` on ALAMI:

```
. . .
us-west-2a.fs-XXXX.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com://remotepath/subdir /mnt/mydev nfs defaults 0 2
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

first do an :umount and then a :mount action

`mount /srv/nfs do
  device "nfsserver://remotepath/subdir"
  fstype 'nfs'
  action [:umount, :disable]
end`

`mount /srv/nfs do
  device "nfsserver://remotepath/subdir"
  fstype 'nfs'
  action [:mount, :enable]
end`

Done